first opensips a simple call- receive a call from a sip client and send it to a sip server-
I have fresh installed opensips and lets say it is running on 192.168.10.50,
what i want is to receive a call from a sip client from an IP 1.1.1.1 and send it to a sip server10.10.10.50
i am receiving a call on opensip, and send a call to the server using simply t_relay, but the opensip is sending the same IP of itself in the request URI host
For example it should send the call to a sip server as 123123@10.10.10.50
but it is sending a call to the server as 123123@192.168.10.50
the IP "192.168.10.50" belongs to itself, it should not do that but it is doing that.
below is an excerpt from routing cf.
socket=udp:192.168.10.50:5060
Route for handling incoming calls
route {
if (is_method("INVITE")) {
    # Modify the request URI if necessary

    # Log the modified request URI for debugging
    xlog("Modified Request URI: $ru\n");

    # Relay the call to the destination SIP server
    if (!send("10.10.10.50:5060")) {
        xlog("Failed to send call to destination server\n");
        exit;
    }
}

}
i was expecting that the opensips will send the call to the sip server with the modified because i am telling him to send("10.10.10.50:5060")
but it does not change
